# QT Windows 7 and RedHat compiler with recast of subclassed item

Tags: qt, redhat

everybody

I'm using QT 5.4.2 and porting an application from windows 7 to RedHat.
I keep receiving an error from the RedHat compiler because of this recasting:

```
QList<HmiQTableWidgetItem01*> modeItemList  =  (QList<HmiQTableWidgetItem01*> &)modeTableWidget->findItems(value, Qt::MatchExactly);
```

while everything seems to be perfectly fine in windows 7 and MS compiler.

Any ideas or tips?

Ciao
Alf

Comment: You need to put the compiler error text. ( It looks as though it is necessary to add a space somewhere)

Comment: Hey Vlad,I was thinking more like to associate the subclassed tablewidgetitem as the "default" item of QWidgetTable. I know it's possible, but I don't remember how. Thanks anyway. I'll be more precise as soon as I'll get the info. Ciao Alf